# How to get folder size with C in Windows?

Tags: c, windows

How can I check if the total size of a folder is smaller than predefined value? Or, the total size of files that have a specific extension, eg *.txt?

I am programming in C, and the program runs in Windows 7.

Comment: If Windows doesn't have a special function for this, you can loop over all files in the directory adding the sizes. If the 'file' is a directory then do a recursive check of that directory.

Comment: and if Windows does have a special function for this, it will be doing exactly what Joachim suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the findfirstfile,findnextfile methods, the structure returned (WIN32_FIND_DATA) contains the file size.

See [FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

To get the filesize you can use the function [GetFileSizeEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364957%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Afaik there is no function to determine the size of a complete folder, but with the mentioned function you can just iterate over all your files and then sum all filesizes up.

Answer (score 0):

First off, apologies that this is win32 code.  But please note that OP
has asked for code in the MS windows platform.  That said, this code CAN be ported to other platforms.  Confidence is high that you only need to replace a handful of basic APIs used in this code:

```
    _findfirst64()  -- start the file-finding process
    _findnext64()   -- continue the file-finding process
    _findclose()    -- end the file-finding process(usually mandatory)
```

...and the related data structure.  Every platform has some form of these functions, yes?

Not much more needs to be said about the code.  It is copiously commented and leverages printf() heavily so you can always see what's going on.  When you go live you'll want to comment-out all those printf()s.

The code will faithfully sum all the files on a drive ( because it will recurse through *everything* ) or it will act upon a single folder.  It just depends on how you call get_dir_size() ( please see its header notes ).

This code is compiled and tested by me today.  Output is an actual screen scrape of the console window while it ran.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE

#if 0
  #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
  #include <windows.h>  
#else
  #define MAX_PATH          260
  typedef int BOOL;
  #define FALSE               0
  #define TRUE                1
#endif 

#include <string.h> /* strcmp() */
#include <stdio.h>  /* printf() */
#include <stdlib.h> /* malloc() */
#include <conio.h>  /* getch() */
#include <io.h>   /* findfirst(), findnext()... */

#define IS_SLASH_TOKEN(x)  (((x)=='\\') || ((x)=='/'))
#define LAST_CHAR(s) (((char *)(s))[strlen((char *)(s)) - 1]) 


/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    valid_directory_name()
    
        - helper for get_dir_size()

    Once upon a time directories beginning with dots were only references to the working or
    parent directories. But now software vendors are creating directories for file 
    storage that may also begin with a dot.
    
    This function will discern a whether a directory is for storage or is a system reference.

    2022.12.02  Created
    2023.07.25 Code streamlined but logic unchanged

*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
BOOL  valid_directory_name(const char *psdir)
{
int iii = -1;
    
    if(psdir)
    {
        /* Is this a dot (.) (working directory) or dot dot (..) parent directory entry?
        * Or is it a legit directory that merely begins with a dot or two ?
        */
        while(psdir[++iii] == '.');
        return (psdir[iii] != '\0');
    }
    return FALSE;
}


/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------

   dir_strcat()

       - helper for get_dir_size()
  
   Properly Combines two direcotry names to form a path, caring for the 
   slash token ('\') as rqr'd.   Make this a forward slash for Unix.

*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void dir_strcat(char *dest, const char *upperDir, const char *lowerDir)
{
    if(IS_SLASH_TOKEN(LAST_CHAR(upperDir)))
        sprintf(dest,"%s%s",  upperDir,lowerDir);
    else 
        sprintf(dest,"%s\\%s",upperDir,lowerDir);
}


/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    get_dir_size()

    Given a folder name, recurses into the folder summing all the file sizes
    found.  If folder contains a sub folder, that folder is parsed too.
    This continues until no more sub folders are found and all the file sizes
    have been summed.
    
    Call with a valid path and the long long sum parameter set to zero, ie:
        size =  get_dir_size("myfolder", 0 );
    
    This is also legit (start at root).  This will sum all the file sizes on the drive:
        size =  get_dir_size("\\", 0 );

    RETURNS: sum of all file sizes found in the folder.
    
*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
long long get_dir_size(char *path, long long sum)
{
char  *wholepath = malloc(MAX_PATH+1);
struct _finddatai64_t sd_fdata ={0};
intptr_t handle;

    if( wholepath ) 
    {
        printf("ENTRY: get_dir_size(%s) entry, malloc OK.\n", path);
        printf("\tCurrent sum %.3f MB.\n",((double)sum/(1024.0*1024.0)));
        dir_strcat(wholepath, path, "*.*"); 
        handle =  _findfirst64(wholepath,  &sd_fdata);
        if(handle != -1)
        {
            do
            {
                if((sd_fdata.attrib & _A_SUBDIR) == _A_SUBDIR) 
                {
                    /* If this is a directory ...*/
                    if(valid_directory_name(sd_fdata.name))
                    {
                        /* ...and this is a valid directory, recurse into it. */
                        dir_strcat(wholepath, path, sd_fdata.name);
                        if(LAST_CHAR(wholepath) != '\\')
                            strcat(wholepath, "\\");
                        sum = get_dir_size( wholepath, sum);
                    }
                }
                else  /* This is a file. Add its size to the running sum */
                {
                    printf("get_dir_size() adding size %.3f KB for file %s\n", 
                        (double)sd_fdata.size/1024.0, sd_fdata.name);
                    sum += sd_fdata.size;
                }
            }while(!_findnext64(handle, &sd_fdata));
            _findclose(handle);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("get_dir_size(%s) BAD HANDLE!!!!\n", path);
        }
        free(wholepath);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("get_dir_size(%s) MEMORY ALLOCATION ERROR!!!!\n", path);
    }
    printf("get_dir_size(%s) Returning sum: %.3f MB.\n", 
        path, (double)sum/(1024.0*1024.0));
    return sum;
}




/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    main()

*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int main()
{
    char path_only[MAX_PATH] = "F:\\PROJECTS\\32bit\\_HELP\\C\\H160";
    long long current_space_used;

    printf("\nStarting path will be: [%s]\n",  path_only);
    current_space_used = get_dir_size( path_only, 0 );
    printf("\n-----------> This path currently uses %.3lf MB <------------ \n", 
        current_space_used/(1024.0*1024.0));
    
    _getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
    Starting path will be: [F:\PROJECTS\32bit\_HELP\C\H160]
    ENTRY: get_dir_size(F:\PROJECTS\32bit\_HELP\C\H160) entry, malloc OK.
            Current sum 0.000 MB.
    get_dir_size() adding size 0.291 KB for file CLEAN.bat
    get_dir_size() adding size 147.000 KB for file CODE.bsc
    ------------ some lines deleted for brevity -------------
    get_dir_size(F:\PROJECTS\32bit\_HELP\C\H160\Debug\) Returning sum: 0.916 MB.
    get_dir_size() adding size 0.191 KB for file EDIT_ALL.bat
    get_dir_size() adding size 7.249 KB for file MAIN.c
    get_dir_size() adding size 0.041 KB for file run.bat
    ENTRY: get_dir_size(F:\PROJECTS\32bit\_HELP\C\H160\Versions\) entry, malloc OK.
            Current sum 0.923 MB.
    get_dir_size() adding size 13.497 KB for file CODE.001.zip
    get_dir_size(F:\PROJECTS\32bit\_HELP\C\H160\Versions\) Returning sum: 0.936 MB.
    get_dir_size(F:\PROJECTS\32bit\_HELP\C\H160) Returning sum: 0.936 MB.

    -----------> This path currently uses 0.936 MB <------------
```